# Create this SOAP XML request with PHP's SOAP extension

Tags: php, api, soap

I'm trying to recreate this XML request using PHP's [SOAP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) and having trouble doing it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.web.stormpost.skylist.com">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <authInfo xmlns:soap="http://skylist.com/services/SoapRequestProcessor" xsi:type="soap:authentication">
      <!--You may enter the following 2 items in any order-->
      <username xsi:type="xsd:string">****@example.com</username>
      <password xsi:type="xsd:string">*******</password>
    </authInfo>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ser:doImportFromTemplate soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <impTempId xsi:type="xsd:int">7</impTempId>
      <data xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="soapenc:string">
Joe|Doe|joe@example.com John|Doe|john@example.com </data>
    </ser:doImportFromTemplate>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is my testing code so far:

```php
// set connection params
$wsdl = 'http://api.stormpost.datranmedia.com/services/SoapRequestProcessor?wsdl';
$namespace = 'https://api.stormpost.datranmedia.com/services/SoapRequestProcessor';
$credentials = (object)array(
    'username' => '****@example.com',
    'password' => '*******'
);
$auth_values = new SoapVar($credentials, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
$header =  new SoapHeader($namespace, "authInfo", $auth_values);

// set client, headers, and call function
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => true));
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));
$client->__soapCall("doImportFromTemplate", array(7, 'Joe|Doe|joe@example.com John|Doe|john@example.com'));
```

It doesn't seem to be implementing the *authInfo* node correctly with the `xsi:type="soap:authentication"` among other things. How should I change my code to output this XML? I'm having trouble finding good implementation examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with the php SOAP client myself a while ago, i didn't really got a full understanding but this worked for me:

```
$auth_values = array('username' => '****@example.com', 'password' => '*******');
$header =  new SoapHeader($namespace, "authInfo", $auth_values, false);

// set client, headers, and call function
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => true));
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up finally getting it working just before this answer but this helps. I didn't know I could skip the whole converting the credentials to an object and assigning it to a SoapVar.

I did find that PulsePoint (formerly StormPost) does *not* like it if you set ```'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2``` in the options array when initializing the SoapClient. I was getting an empty object when I added that.